# How to configure the Github Atom editor to open a new blank file at launch time?

Tags: file, github, editor, atom-editor

I am using the Github Atom editor version 1.8.0 under Kubuntu 16.04.

I would like to know if there is a way to open a **new blank file** every time I launch the editor. At this point in time, every time I open the editor, I need manually to click on **File -> New File (Ctrl + N)**.

In other editors up there, if I am not opening an existing file, they tend to open a blank file automatically. I am sure that there must be a way to accomplish such a simple thing in Atom as well.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Strange https://discuss.atom.io/t/preference-not-to-open-new-file-when-opening-atom/8476/15 suggests the opposite issue...

Comment: @VonC: That topic was discussed in 2014. I wish to learn how to activate this feature. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it seems that feature was active by default back then

Answer (score 1):

It appears the bug has been fixed as of Atom v1.14. To clarify for future readers, adjust the following options in `Settings > Core` to open Atom with a blank file:

`Open Empty Editor On Start` should be *checked*
[image: Open Empty Editor On Start]

`Restore Previous Windows On Start` should be *unchecked*
[image: Restore Previous Windows On Start]

With these options enabled, Atom writes the following lines into `config.cson`:

```
"*":
  core:
    restorePreviousWindowsOnStart: false
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
```

Opening `atom -n` via the command line should perform the same task (although if the options are already selected in Atom settings, simply running `atom` will also open a blank file).

Answer (score 0):

While I can't reproduce your problem on OS X (it launches with an untitled document), you can use `atom -n` to launch Atom with a new window.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly the "atom -n" command is not working up with me as well. It is launching the Atom editor indeed but it is not opening an untitled empty document. The command "atom -n" is behaving exactly the same as "atom". Although your answer sounds very logical, sadly it did not work out for me. Any other hack to try?

Comment: To make certain there is no other package interfering, try `atom -n --safe` (or simply `atom --safe`). This will launch Atom without any third-party packages.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. "atom -n --safe" worked well; it opened up the Atom editor with a new untitled blank document as I want it. However "Atom --safe" behaved exactly the same as "Atom" and "Atom -n". Besides that, I found under the settings tab an option that says: "Open Empty Editor On Start". This option though is not getting triggered for some reason. Do you think a certain package is conflicting with the -n flag?

Comment: [Update]: It is not working all the time. Sometimes it is working, other times it is not. I am trying to repeat the same command multiple times to get it to work. That is "Atom -n --safe". Extremely weird!

Comment: [Update]: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/10623 | This seems to explain my issue very well.